# Testing ruby superclass inherited functionality with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given that I have an abstract class which provides inherited functionality to subclasses:

```
class Superclass
  class_attribute :_configuration_parameter

  def self.configuration_parameter config
    self._configuration_parameter = config
  end

  def results
    unless @queried
      execute
      @queried = true
    end

    @results
  end

  private

  # Execute uses the class instance config
  def execute
    @rows = DataSource.fetch self.class._configuration_parameter
    @results = Results.new @rows, count
    post_process
  end

  def post_process
    @results.each do |row|
      # mutate results
    end
  end
end
```

Which might be used by a subclass like this:

```
class Subclass < Superclass
  configuration_parameter :foo

  def subclass_method
  end
end
```

I'm having a hard time writing RSpec to test the inherited and configured functionality without abusing the global namespace:

```
RSpec.describe Superclass do
  let(:config_parameter) { :bar }

  let(:test_subclass) do
    # this feels like an anti-pattern, but the Class.new block scope
    # doesn't contain config_parameter from the Rspec describe

    $config_parameter = config_parameter

    Class.new(Superclass) do
      configuration_parameter $config_parameter
    end
  end

  let(:test_instance) do
    test_subclass.new
  end

  describe 'config parameter' do
    it 'sets the class attribute' do
      expect(test_subclass._configuration_parameter).to be(config_parameter)
    end
  end

  describe 'execute' do
    it 'fetches the data from the right place' do
      expect(DataSource).to receive(:fetch).with(config_parameter)
      instance.results
    end
  end
end
```

The real world superclass I'm mocking here has a few more configuration parameters and several other pieces of functionality which test reasonably well with this pattern.

Am I missing something obviously bad about the class or test design?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if the part commented in the code is something bad? Personally I think it looks ugly, I would just use a before(:each) block, but the question is not really clear. If you are asking for the whole tests file, I think you have to read aboutr shared_examples on rspec, I think it will work a lot better to test this things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to jump to the most concrete part of your question, about how to avoid using a global variable to pass a local parameter to the dummy class instantiated in your spec.

Here's your spec code:

```
let(:test_subclass) do
  # this feels like an anti-pattern, but the Class.new block scope
  # doesn't contain config_parameter from the Rspec describe

  $config_parameter = config_parameter

  Class.new(Superclass) do
    configuration_parameter $config_parameter
  end
end
```

If you take the value returned from `Class.new` you can call `configuration_parameter` on that with the local value and avoid the global. Using `tap` does this with only a minor change to your existing code:

```
let(:test_subclass) do
  Class.new(SuperClass).tap do |klass|
    klass.configuration_parameter config_parameter
  end
end
```

As to the more general question of how to test functionality inherited from a superclass, I think the general approach of creating a stub subclass and writing specs for that subclass is fine. I personally would make your `_configuration_parameter` class attribute private, and rather than testing that the `configuration_parameter` method actually sets the value, I'd instead focus on checking that the value is *different* from the superclass value. But I'm not sure that's in the scope of this question.

Comment: That's the sane suggestion I was looking for. I appreciate the sanity check and more general advice on the patterns too

Comment: Glad the answer helped!